# DAX, Power BI - Concatenate strings

Tags: powerbi, dax

Does anyone know a DAX that could concatenate rows for the example in the image? I want to create a new measure that would englobe all countries together but summing up the repeated ones. BR + BRA would be Brasil.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02eGM.png)

I can add up the values for those countries in a DAX which would return numbers, but I am interested in strings specifically. Something like "if in country BR and BRA then Brasil, if in country CH and CHI then Chile".

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with concatenating strings. It sounds like you need a calculated column that labels both versions with a common name.

Comment: Hi @AlexisOlson! Yes, I need a new measure with a DAX included. Just added a new picture in another comment. Any tip? :( many thanks

Comment: Just edited my post with the new image @AlexisOlson

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column that unifies the countries.

```
all_countries =
SWITCH(
    TRUE();
    'panelCmd'[country] IN { "BR", "BRA" }; "Brasil";
    'panelCmd'[country] IN { "CH", "CHI" }; "Chile";
    'panelCmd'[country] IN { "ES", "ESP" }; "Spain";
    <...et cetera...>
    'panelCmd'[country]
)
```

Then you can use that column in your table instead of / in addition to `country`.

---

Reference on `SWITCH(TRUE()...)`: [The Diabolical Genius of “SWITCH TRUE”](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a measure that concatenate multiple strings into a single comma-delimited string? 
If so, you may want to use CONCATENATEX iterator. More specifically, in Power BI Desktop, you can create a measure using the Quick Measure option, and then selecting the "concatenate..." option at the bottom. This will give you a code snippet that does that, and a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

use & to concatenate strings

Ex:

"String1 " & "String2" & " String3" => String1 String2 String3

```
Subheading = "for events that occured up to "& FORMAT(TODAY(),"DD") & "th  " & FORMAT(TODAY(),"MMMM") & "
```

**Result:** for events that occured up to 16th December

[image]